# bicep/arm template how to get display name of location

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

In bicep or arm template, how to get display location name?
Eg, I have input location name 'westus', I want to get its displayName like 'West US' since I have to put location name in an alert condition like:
`{ field: 'properties.impactedServices[*].ImpactedRegions[*].RegionName' containsAny: [ 'west us' ] }`

By the way, ``listLocations('/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${toLower(location)}', '2016-06-01').displayName 
which seems not work.

Comment: notice that 'west us' is ok but still don't know how to do with input..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think thats possible. ie [this list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-resource#list) doesnt show that is supported. and `list*` operations are actually `HTTP PUT` requests, not `HTTP GET`.

So I'd expect you'd need to add that data to the template